# Terraform complex output from resource with dynamic blocks

Tags: terraform

I have a resource like this:

```
resource "yandex_mdb_mysql_cluster" "main" {
      + allow_regeneration_host = false
      + created_at              = (known after apply)
      + description             = "Multi node MySQL cluster created with Terraform"
      + environment             = "PRODUCTION"
      + health                  = (known after apply)
      + id                      = (known after apply)
      + labels                  = {
          + "env" = "dev"
        }
      + name                    = (known after apply)
      + status                  = (known after apply)
      + version                 = "5.7"

      + access {
          + data_lens = false
          + web_sql   = true
        }

      + backup_window_start {
          + hours   = 1
          + minutes = 0
        }

      + host {
          + assign_public_ip = false
          + fqdn             = (known after apply)
          + subnet_id        = (known after apply)
          + zone             = "ru-central1-a"
        }
      + host {
          + assign_public_ip = false
          + fqdn             = (known after apply)
          + subnet_id        = (known after apply)
          + zone             = "ru-central1-b"
        }
      + host {
          + assign_public_ip = false
          + fqdn             = (known after apply)
          + subnet_id        = (known after apply)
          + zone             = "ru-central1-c"
        }
```

Now I want to set up an output which gets data from dynamic `host` block in map form like `host.zone = host.fqdn`, like:

```
{ru-central1-a = "fqdn-a"
ru-central1-b = "fqdn-b"
ru-central1-c = "fqdn-c"}
```

I've tried running for loop over whole resource taking host.zone and host.fqdn but it doesn't seem to work...
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like this?

```
output x {
  value = { for v in yandex_mdb_mysql_cluster.main.host: v.zone => v.fqdn }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I did something like this, but the problem was totally unrelated-this resource was inside the optional module with count and conditional and when I tried to return this output without [0] index (module.databases.hosts_fqdn instead of module.databases[0].hosts_fqdn) Terraform gave me not-so-useful error "This value does not have any attributes." Anyway, your solution forced me to look for an error in other places, thanks! =)